# Escape unescaped values in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping

I have troubles with xslt transformation where the original xml doesn't have escaped characters like doublequote.

I am testing with xsltproc but I didn't manage to handle proper result. I searched for a solution a lot but it seems that I cannot find the right solution for my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Source xml:

```
<test>abc"abc"</test>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        &lt;test2 property=&quot;<xsl:value-of select="./test"/>&quot; /&gt;
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        &lt;test2 property="abc"abc"" /&gt;
```

Result I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    &lt;test2 property="abc&quot;abc&quot;" /&gt;
```

Verbose output:

```
xsltProcessOneNode: applying template '/' for /
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy text 
        <test2 property="
xsltCopyText: copy text 
        <test2 property="
xsltValueOf: select ./test
xsltCopyTextString: copy text abc"abc"
xsltValueOf: result 'abc"abc"'
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: copy text " />

xsltCopyText: copy text " />

freeing transformation dictionary
freeing dictionary from stylesheet
```

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**

New findings: If I add & sign, it is correctly escaped into & but " is not. I thought that it should be escaped as well, based on what I read on the internet.

Comment: Is the expected output in your question totally correct? Shouldn't it be `&lt;test2 property="abc&quot;abc&quot;" /&gt;`?

Comment: If it's supposed to be escaped markup then it would actually need to be `&lt;test2 property="abc&amp;quot;abc&amp;quot;" /&gt;` with the double-quotes escaped twice so they end up as `&quot;` after one round of un-escaping.